# Merge Hyperlink, href, and Links tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I believe the following SO tags should be merged as they all mean the same thing: [hyperlink](/questions/tagged/hyperlink) [href](/questions/tagged/href) [links](/questions/tagged/links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a technicality, but a `<link>` tag is distinct from a hyperlink, which refers to the `<a>` tag, so they shouldn't really be merged in my opinion. The `href` attribute is shared by both of these, so I guess having this tag around isn't necessary.

Comment: That is a good argument for merging into [tag:link] rather than [tag:hyperlink], but not for preventing the merge. All hyperlinks are links, but not all links are hyperlinks. That being said, a hyperlink is nowhere near unique enough to warrant a separate tag from general links. **Edit:** [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), they are synonyms.

Comment: @animuson The usage of `<link>` tags is significantly different from the usage of hyperlinks. One is used to load resources, while the other is used to provide an interface for navigation. The words link and hyperlink are synonyms in common usage, but they refer to different concepts in HTML, which is why they deserve separate tags. What Wikipedia or OED have to say about it is not very relevant.

Comment: Really, they're not *that* different. A `<link>` is still just a link to an external page, and the relation specified on it tells the browser what that page is. The only really difference is that a `<link>` goes in the header to **make semantic sense** because it wouldn't make sense to define it in the body of the page, whereas an anchor link has a different semantic meaning and is used inline with the text of the page. That's the only difference -- semantics. They really *aren't* different enough to warrant separate tags.

Comment: @animuson Yes, but my point is that their usage is significantly different. Technically `img` tags, `script` tags etc. are all just links too, but we wouldn't want a link or hyperlink tag on questions pertaining to those.

Answer (score 1):

[href](/questions/tagged/href) is referring to the href attribute of a `<a>` tag. We could debate about the need of having that tag, but it's not a synonym of the other tags.
Tag synonyms are created when two tags with the same meaning are used; they are also created when there are users who keep typoing a tag, for example writing [druapl-view](/questions/tagged/druapl-view) instead of [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views).

[hyperlink](/questions/tagged/hyperlink), and [links](/questions/tagged/links) are synonym, and they should be merged.
I would keep [links](/questions/tagged/links), and make the other one its synonym, but also doing the opposite would be fine with me.

Comment: I can see the point, however, if I see `href` I think link or hyperlink. When you read the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/href/info) for href it is all about hyperlinks. As for the difference between Hyperlink and Link I agree with you either is fine and I personally do not have a preference either way.

Comment: The fact one tag makes you think to the other one doesn't mean they are synonym.

Comment: I would say that [tag:href] is an adequate synonym. An anchor with a `href` attribute *is* a link by definition, so tagging a question with [tag:html] and [tag:hyperlink] would imply the use of an anchor with a `href` attribute perfectly fine.

Comment: A `<link>` isn't necessarily a hyperlink (`<a>`), even though both utilize the href attribute.

Comment: I don't think "synonym" has to be the English dictionary meaning and not a Stack Exchange specific meaning. And even if you do want to force it to be so strict, then "link" technically has many more meanings that "hyperlink" doesn't have. You can't have it both ways. Either merge things which "mean the same thing for this site by what is tagged and/or what the wiki says" or "merge by exact English definition of synonym", but merging at some hard to pinpoint arbitrary place between just is going to be inconsistent and an exercise in futility.

Comment: @hippietrail _Synonym_ doesn't mean "is part of." _href_ is an attribute for a link, but it's not a synonym of _link_. _Link_ is a short for _hyperlink_. The tag wiki for [tag:links] says, "A hyperlink is a reference to a document or a part of a document that can be followed automatically." What is arbitrary?